# I have Week and year in php I need to convert date complete

Tags: php, date

I have Week and year in php I need to convert date complete, I'm new in php help please

```
<?php

  $weekY = date('Wy' ,strtotime('-1 week')); 
  print_r(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($weekY)));

?>
```

the result is 1970-01-01

and I have the 5113(Wy) in my database how to convert in Wy

```
<?php

 $weekY = date('Wy' ,strtotime(5113)); 
  echo $weekY."<br/>";

?>
```

the result is 0170

I read examples but do not help me in my problem

Comment: Why are you converting a timestamp to `Wy` format only to convert it back to a timestamp? Are you trying to make your own life difficult? If so, mission accomplished.

Comment: RTFM: [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) accepts a **UNIX TIMESTAMP** as its input. `5113`  correponds to 1:25:13 AM, Jan 1, 1970. You can't make up your own date/time formats and stuff them into PHP's time systems and expect them to "just work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everything, and I have the answer to my question

```
<?php
$y = substr('5213',-2);
$Y = 20..$y;

$W = substr('5213',0,2);
echo "Year + Week: ".$Y." ".$W."<br/>";

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setISODate($Y, $W);
echo "Result: ".$date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [`setISODate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
<?php
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2013,52);//year and week
echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y'); //"prints" 23-12-2013
```